# Requiring a bytes32 mapping to be empty, why does my transaction fail?

Tags: mapping, bytes, failed-transaction

I have a contract here: [contract source code](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xc25249bb74dd83a0470a0df7e5c93bdaffb300e9#code)

It's a simple one that allows users to create new key:value mappings with bytes32 variables, as well as update the value of a key given that:

1. the key is owned (was initially set by) the `msg.sender`
2. the mapping is not empty (which I express by doing `require(items[key] != 0)`

However I get a transaction [reverted](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x630ce3dc4b70942ea5ba9121f70b6f566ddb9fa9e67b62a2e8436ea9208acc49) when trying to update even with the user being the one who initially set the key:value and it being not empty. Could anyone tell me why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the reverted tx above you are calling `setItem` again which is failing due to probably trying to override a value that's already set. Check the transaction using the [tenderly dashboard](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/rinkeby/0x630ce3dc4b70942ea5ba9121f70b6f566ddb9fa9e67b62a2e8436ea9208acc49/contracts) for more in-depth logs and easier debugging.

Apart from that, your contract works as intended ([set value tx](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xa1359df37893e88437cdd326ff09a31e36a7c005ccd45041ee59d62780fb6beb), [change value tx](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xc7edb927421714191f4f4ff90e13111e6e6b81cad925efa52bfd16a57ff922ec))

Comment: Wow, how embarrassing... I need to do better to double check what's in front of me. Thank you for that and introducing me to Tenderly. Cheers.